How to Replace IN Operator with JOIN in Dynamic Criteria Using JPA Specification?
I have a requirement to build a dynamic filter criteria based on filters I receive. Initially, I used the Specification approach, and it is working as expected in production. However, the new requirement is that I need to call an SQL function and use the output to build my criteria.
To achieve this, I used a native query approach through the JPA repository to call the SQL function and prepare a list of cities and states based on the source and destination locations. I passed the result to the IN operator, but I received the following exception while calling SQL function: Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request.
I need a solution that integrates with my existing code to meet this new requirement without breaking the dynamic criteria building for other filters.
Request Payload:
{
    "pageNumber": 1,
    "pageSize": 20,
    "laneFilters": [
        {
            "fieldName": "destinationCity",
            "fieldType": "Text",
            "operation": "Equals",
            "valueOne": "Chicago",
            "values": null
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "destinationState",
            "fieldType": "Text",
            "operation": "Equals",
            "valueOne": "IL",
            "values": null
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "originCity",
            "fieldType": "Text",
            "operation": "Equals",
            "valueOne": "Atlanta",
            "values": null
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "originState",
            "fieldType": "Text",
            "operation": "Equals",
            "valueOne": "GA",
            "values": null
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "modeName",
            "fieldType": "Text",
            "operation": "Contains",
            "valueOne": "tl",
            "values": null
        }
    ],
    "carrierId": null
}

Service Layer Code:
@Override
public List<LaneEntity> getAllLanes(LanePageableDTO lanePageable) throws ServiceException {
    Map<String, String> fieldNameAndValueMap = processCarrierFilters(lanePageable.getLaneFilters());
    Map<Boolean, Map<String, List<String>>> cityStatePartitionedMap = getCityAndStatePartitionedData(
        Optional.ofNullable(fieldNameAndValueMap.get(Constants.FIELD_NAME_ORIGIN_CITY)).orElse(null),
        Optional.ofNullable(fieldNameAndValueMap.get(Constants.FIELD_NAME_ORIGIN_STATE)).orElse(null),
        Optional.ofNullable(fieldNameAndValueMap.get(Constants.FIELD_NAME_DESTINATION_CITY)).orElse(null),
        Optional.ofNullable(fieldNameAndValueMap.get(Constants.FIELD_NAME_DESTINATION_STATE)).orElse(null)
    );
    LaneFilterSpecification filterSpecification = new LaneFilterSpecification(
        lanePageable.getLaneFilters(),
        lanePageable.getCarrierId(), cityStatePartitionedMap
    );
    return laneRepository.findAll(filterSpecification);
}

SQL Function Call and Data Construction Logic:
This is just entity for reference table in not exists in database. I am using SQL Plus as database.
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ZipCodeEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3365453943900329675L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Zip")
    private String zip;

    @Column(name = "LocationType")
    private String locationType;

    @Column(name = "Radius")
    private Integer radius;

    @Column(name = "City")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "StateCode")
    private String stateCode;
}

@Repository
public interface ZipCodeRepository extends JpaRepository<ZipCodeEntity, Long> {

    @Query(value = "WITH CTE_ZipCodes AS (" + "SELECT Zip, LocationType, Radius, City, StateCode "
            + "FROM [dbo].[GetZipCodeWithinRadius](0, :callerScreen, :srcCity, :srcState, :dstCity, :dstState, 150, 150)"
            + ") SELECT * FROM CTE_ZipCodes", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ZipCodeEntity> findZipCodesWithinRadius(@Param("callerScreen") String callerScreen,
            @Param("srcCity") String srcCity, @Param("srcState") String srcState, @Param("dstCity") String dstCity,
            @Param("dstState") String dstState);
}

Output of SQL Function:

Partitioned City and State Data Construction Logic:
private Map<String, String> processCarrierFilters(List<CarrierPreferredLaneFilter> carrierPreferredLaneFilters) {
        // Create a map to retrieve specific values based on fieldName
        return carrierPreferredLaneFilters.stream()
                // Only include filters with non-null values
                .filter(filter -> filter.getValueOne() != null)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(CarrierPreferredLaneFilter::getFieldName,
                        CarrierPreferredLaneFilter::getValueOne,
                        // in case of duplicates, keep the existing value
                        (existing, replacement) -> existing));
    }
    
    private Map<Boolean, Map<String, List<String>>> getCityAndStatePartitionedData(String srcCity, String srcState, String dstCity, String dstState) {
         // Fetch all records in a single query
        List<ZipCodeEntity> zipCodes = zipCodeRepository.findZipCodesWithinRadius(
            "Lane", srcCity, srcState, dstCity, dstState
        );

        // Partition the data and extract city and state lists in one go
        return zipCodes.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
                zipCode -> "Source".equalsIgnoreCase(zipCode.getLocationType()),
                Collectors.collectingAndThen( 
                    Collectors.toList(),
                    list -> Map.of(
                        "cities", list.stream().map(ZipCodeEntity::getCity).collect(Collectors.toList()),
                        "states", list.stream().map(ZipCodeEntity::getStateCode).collect(Collectors.toList())
                    )
                )
            ));
    }

Specification Logic (Partial):
public class LaneFilterSpecification implements Specification<LaneEntity> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5817708002524725894L;

    private List<LaneFilter> laneFilters;

    private Long carrierId;
    
    private Map<Boolean, Map<String, List<String>>> cityStatePartitionedMap;
    
    public LaneFilterSpecification(List<LaneFilter> laneFilters,
            Long carrierId, Map<Boolean, Map<String, List<String>>> cityStatePartitionedMap) {
        super();
        this.laneFilters = laneFilters;
        this.carrierId = carrierId;
        this.cityStatePartitionedMap = cityStatePartitionedMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<LaneEntity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
            CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (nonNull(laneFilters) && !laneFilters.isEmpty()) {
            for (LaneFilter laneFilter : laneFilters) {

                String operation = StringUtils.isNotBlank(laneFilter.getOperation())
                        ? laneFilter.getOperation().toLowerCase()
                        : StringUtils.EMPTY;

                switch (FilterOperationEnum.getOperation(operation)) {
                case CONTAINS:
                    addFilterContains(predicates, root, criteriaBuilder, laneFilter);
                    break;
                case NOT_CONTAINS:
                    addFilterNotContains(predicates, root, criteriaBuilder, laneFilter);
                    break;
                case EQUALS:
                    addFilterEquals(predicates, root, criteriaBuilder, laneFilter);
                    break;
                case GREATER_THAN:
                    addFilterGreaterThan(predicates, root, criteriaBuilder, laneFilter);
                    break;
                case GREATER_THAN_EQUAL:
                    addFilterGreaterThanEquals(predicates, root, criteriaBuilder, laneFilter);
                    break;
                case LESS_THAN:
                    addFilterLessThan(predicates, root, criteriaBuilder, laneFilter);
                    break;
                case LESS_THAN_EQUAL:
                    addFilterLessThanEquals(predicates, root, criteriaBuilder, laneFilter);
                    break;
                case IN_RANGE:
                    addFilterInRange(predicates, root, criteriaBuilder, laneFilter);
                    break;
                case IN:
                    addFilterIN(predicates, root, criteriaBuilder, laneFilter);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

                }
            }
        }

        if (nonNull(carrierId)) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(carrierJoin(root).get(Constants.FIELD_NAME_CARRIER_ID), carrierId));
        }

        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }

    private void addFilterEquals(List<Predicate> predicates, Root<LaneEntity> root,
            CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, LaneFilter laneFilter) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(laneFilter.getValueOne())) {
            String trimmedValueOne = laneFilter.getValueOne().trim().toUpperCase();
            if (laneFilter.getFieldName().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.FIELD_NAME_ORIGIN_CITY)) {
                if (isNull(carrierId) && !cityStatePartitionedMap.isEmpty()
                        && !cityStatePartitionedMap.get(Boolean.TRUE).isEmpty()
                        && !cityStatePartitionedMap.get(Boolean.TRUE).get("cities").isEmpty()
                        && !cityStatePartitionedMap.get(Boolean.TRUE).get("states").isEmpty()) {
                    addFilterIN(predicates, root, criteriaBuilder, laneFilter);
                } else {
                    Predicate pOriginCity = criteriaBuilder
                            .equal(criteriaBuilder.upper(root.get(Constants.FIELD_NAME_ORIGIN_CITY)), trimmedValueOne);
                    
                    Predicate pOriginState = criteriaBuilder
                            .equal(criteriaBuilder.upper(root.get(Constants.FIELD_NAME_ORIGIN_STATE)), trimmedValueOne);
                    
                    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.or(pOriginCity, pOriginState));                  
                }
            } else if (laneFilter.getFieldName()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.FIELD_NAME_DESTINATION_CITY)) {
                if (isNull(carrierId) && !cityStatePartitionedMap.isEmpty()
                        && !cityStatePartitionedMap.get(Boolean.FALSE).isEmpty()
                        && !cityStatePartitionedMap.get(Boolean.FALSE).get("cities").isEmpty()
                        && !cityStatePartitionedMap.get(Boolean.FALSE).get("states").isEmpty()) {
                    addFilterIN(predicates, root, criteriaBuilder, laneFilter);
                } else {
                    Predicate pDestinationCity = criteriaBuilder
                            .equal(criteriaBuilder.upper(root.get(Constants.FIELD_NAME_DESTINATION_CITY)), trimmedValueOne);

                    Predicate pDestinationState = criteriaBuilder.equal(
                            criteriaBuilder.upper(root.get(Constants.FIELD_NAME_DESTINATION_STATE)), trimmedValueOne);

                    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.or(pDestinationCity, pDestinationState));
                }
            } else {
                if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(laneFilter.getFieldType())) {
                    switch (FilterFieldTypeEnum.getFieldType(laneFilter.getFieldType().toLowerCase())) {
                    case TEXT:
                        addTextFilterEquals(predicates, root, criteriaBuilder, laneFilter);
                        break;
                    case NUMBER:
                        addNumberFilterEquals(predicates, root, criteriaBuilder, laneFilter);
                        break;
                    case DATE:
                        addDateFilterEquals(predicates, root, criteriaBuilder, laneFilter);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }


    private void addFilterIN(List<Predicate> predicates, Root<LaneEntity> root,
            CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, LaneFilter laneFilter) {
        
        if (isNull(carrierId)) {
            if (Constants.FIELD_NAME_ORIGIN_CITY.equalsIgnoreCase(laneFilter.getFieldName())) {
                Predicate orgCityInPredicate = root.get(Constants.FIELD_NAME_ORIGIN_CITY)
                        .in(cityStatePartitionedMap.get(Boolean.TRUE).get("cities"));
                Predicate orgStateInPredicate = root.get(Constants.FIELD_NAME_ORIGIN_STATE)
                        .in(cityStatePartitionedMap.get(Boolean.TRUE).get("states"));
                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(orgCityInPredicate, orgStateInPredicate));
            }

            if (Constants.FIELD_NAME_DESTINATION_CITY.equalsIgnoreCase(laneFilter.getFieldName())) {
                Predicate orgCityInPredicate = root.get(Constants.FIELD_NAME_DESTINATION_CITY)
                        .in(cityStatePartitionedMap.get(Boolean.FALSE).get("cities"));
                Predicate orgStateInPredicate = root.get(Constants.FIELD_NAME_DESTINATION_STATE)
                        .in(cityStatePartitionedMap.get(Boolean.FALSE).get("states"));

                predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(orgCityInPredicate, orgStateInPredicate));
            }
        }
    }

    private Join<LaneEntity, CarrierEntity> carrierJoin(Root<LaneEntity> root) {
        return root.join(Constants.FIELD_NAME_CARRIER, JoinType.INNER);
    }
}

Problem: Currently, I am using the IN operator to filter based on cities and states, but I hit the SQL Server limit for parameters (2100). I need to replace the IN operator with a JOIN in the SQL query to avoid this issue.
I didn't provide whole specification code as it's too long but I tried with this approach and get above mentioned error.
How can I refactor the existing JPA Specification code to replace the IN operator with a JOIN based on the data fetched from the SQL function, and ensure that the dynamic criteria building for other filters is not affected?
Prompt assistance will be highly appreciated!
I tried with IN operator as I mentioned above.

I'm not going to analyze your code. It's to complex. But I know that in place of IN you can try to use nested SELECT.

I can explain it by connecting over any other platform. @Mar-Z

I know that it may be a sub-optimal solution, but have you tried to split the cityStatePartitionedMap.get(Boolean.TRUE).get("cities") list to smaller size chunks (less than 1000 elements cad), create an in clause for each of these and assemble them in an or constraint? This is likely what is done by some frameworks when dealin with in clause and lists of more than 1000 elements.

Thank you @FrancescoPoli Poli I tried to divide and applied in batch but still my IN clause will have more number of parameters hence we are getting more response time.
